# `X1:Y1|X2:Y2..` transformation to `X1 Y1..` for a text file in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a text file contains following data

```
X1:Y1|X2:Y2|X3:Y3|X4:Y4|X5:Y5
```

I want to achieve this output

```
X1 Y1
X2 Y2
X3 Y3
X4 Y4
X5 Y5
```

Now I've been trying to achieve this way but couldn't get

I have tried following code:

```
scala> val input = sc.textFile("/home/bhaskar/Desktop/log.txt")
input: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = /home/bhaskar/Desktop/log.txt MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:24

scala> val rdd1 = input.flatMap(line => line.split('|'))
rdd1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[23] at flatMap at <console>:26
```

Got following different output:

```
scala> for(x <- rdd1){println(x)}
X1:Y1
X2:Y2
X3:Y3
X4:Y4
X5:Y5

scala> for(x <- rdd1){println(x.split(":"))}
[Ljava.lang.String;@3ce3bfde
[Ljava.lang.String;@7752bb7c
[Ljava.lang.String;@3af05705
[Ljava.lang.String;@2296f59c
[Ljava.lang.String;@3aaa35f

scala> for(x <- rdd1){println(x.split(":").toString())}
[Ljava.lang.String;@36154dc9
[Ljava.lang.String;@586b85e5
[Ljava.lang.String;@1436d0d6
[Ljava.lang.String;@21295bb6
[Ljava.lang.String;@3dce215f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply replace all colons `":"` with blank-space `" "` and all pipes `"|"` with a new line `"\n"`. Try following code

```
val str = "X1:Y1|X2:Y2|X3:Y3|X4:Y4|X5:Y5"

val foramttedStr = str.replaceAll(":"," ").replaceAll("\\|","\n")

print(foramttedStr)

//output
// X1 Y1
// X2 Y2
// X3 Y3
// X4 Y4
// X5 Y5
```

Using similar thing in your `Spark` program you can use following code,

```
val rdd1: RDD[String] = input.map(line => line.replaceAll(":"," ").replaceAll("\\|","\n"))

rdd1.foreach(println(_))
```

It will produce same output as above.

Answer (score 0):

```
input.flatMap(line => line.split('|'))
  .foreach(line => println(line.split(":").mkString(" ")))
```

You are trying to print out a list of `String`s -- instead you should concatenate it's elements beforehand.

Comment: Thanks a lot but sorry! The output of your query is showing 
`X
1

Y
1
|
X
2

Y
2
|
X
3

Y
3
|
X
4

Y
4
|
X
5

Y
5
rdd1: Unit = ()`

Vertically

Comment: @BhaskarDas It works perfectly fine for me, make sure you split by `'|'` not "|" - if you want to use a string, you have to escape pipe symbol with backslash because it is treated as regular expression then - "\\|"

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to just replace the characters:

```
input.replace(":", " ").replace("|", "\n")
```

However, in my opinion it's always advisable to transform your input into the appropriate data structure (in this case I chose a `Seq[(String, String)]` but YMMV of course):

```
val parsed: Seq[(String, String)] = input.
  split('|').               // split by '|'
  iterator.                 // avoid creating intermediate collections
  map(s => s.split(':')).   // split each "line" by ':'
  map(a => a(0) -> a(1)).   // transform each "line" from an array to a pair
  toSeq                     // collect into the resulting sequence
```

So that then we can use it more freely.

Given this structure, it's pretty easy now to print what you originally wanted:

```
for ((a, b) <- parsed) {
  println(s"$a $b")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code `x.split('|')` is producing a Java Array which is being printed as `[Ljava.lang.String;@36154dc9`

There are many Google or SO answers about printing a Java Array but in Scala you could do;

```
scala> for(x <- rdd1) { println(x.split(":").mkString(" ")) }
```